xarray coordinates in multiindex don't match
I have a xarray with dimensions lat and long  on which i stacked lat and long to a multiindex.
xarray = xr.open_dataset(nc_path, engine="netcdf4")

xarray_stacked = xarray.stack(coords=("latitude", "longitude"))

xarray_stacked["latitude"][3].item()

gives me:
55.699999999999996

when using .sel to grab a value i would normaly just use "method = "nearest" but that doesn' work on a multiindex.
my question is how i can make something like this work:
xarray_stacked.sel(coords = (55.7, x))

currently this gives an error.
i tried all sorts of rounding (np.round) etc
